# How to resolve timeout: can't execute '/bin/bash': No such file or directory error?

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab, timeout

I am writing a yaml anchor in `.gitlab-ci.yml` as below:

```
.docker_daemon_to_start: &docker_daemon_to_start
    - timeout 300 /bin/bash -c -- 'while ! docker info; do sleep 1; done'
```

In the above command I have tried both `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/bash`, but the pipeline is giving an error as,

```
timeout: can't execute '/bin/bash': No such file or directory
```

Is there any to fix this error to get the pipeline in running state?

Comment: Can you add your docker file or docker compose yml? What image are you using for your docker container?

Comment: If you are using minimum versions of the images like `alpine`, there's no bash shell in them.

Comment: @DreamBold Yes I am using alpine image "node:16-alpine3.16". what is the solution for that?

Comment: Just change it `node:16` and it will work

Comment: It might also work to replace `/bin/bash` with `/bin/sh` (I don't see anything there that actually requires bash).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using minimum versions of the images like `alpine`, there's no bash shell in them. Just change it to `node:16` and the bash will work.

Comment: Using ```/bin/sh``` instead of ```/bin/bash``` worked and changing the docker image to ```node:16``` also worked.